# NodeJS module.export - Person is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm following a tutorial about Node.JS custom modules.
Inside a folder named lib, I created the file Person.js:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

util.inherits(Person, EventEmitter);

module.exports = Person;
```

Next, I created the file custom-module.js:

```
var Person = require('./lib/Person');

var ben = new Person("Benjamin Franklin");
```

Then, when I run node custom-module.js I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Person is not a constructor
```

If, in custom-module.js, a insert the comand

```
console.log(Person)
```

I get the following:

```
{ Person: 
   { [Function: Person]
     super_: 
      { [Function: EventEmitter]
        EventEmitter: [Circular],
        usingDomains: false,
        defaultMaxListeners: [Getter/Setter],
        init: [Function],
        listenerCount: [Function] } } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `console.log(Person);`

Comment: Code is fine, check whether the `Person.js` is inside lib folder

Comment: @user2671169 is this a specific browser related issue ?

Comment: @Kalana NodeJS doesn't run in the browser. It's a server-side scripting engine.

Comment: According to your `console.log(Person)`, `new Person.Person('Benjamin Franklin')` should work. But why it’s exported that way, I don’t know… It seems like you’re not setting `module.exports = Person` as your snippet shows but rather `exports.Person = Person`.